# How to Create sub domain for every user in AWS Cloud

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Can Any one guide me how to create a subdomain for every user in AWS cloud?

Development Stack, I am using is PHP & Mysql

Comment: This may help you [ http://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/CreatingNewSubdomain.html ]

Comment: Not really clear what you are asking.  Create a subdomain... and then what?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot create a subdomain for every user dynamically...

Comment: @NN not helped :( its creating sub domain.. I want it to dynamically.

Comment: Still not 100% sure where you're going with the question but I have added an answer.  This is what I use for this purpose.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In Route 53, you can create a wildcard subdomain.

If you have a domain example.com, and an example.com hosted zone in Route 53, you simply create a new A record there with the hostname `*`.  Then, *anything*.example.com that doesn't already have an entry in the hosted zone will return the value of that `A` record.  Or you can create a sub-sub domain, like `*.userpages.example.com` so that *anything*.userpages.example.com would work.  For this, you'd create an A record called `*.userpages`.  There's no need for an additional hosted zone for the subdomain.

If that A record is pointing to your application server, then it only remains for your application server to examine the incoming HTTP `Host:` header and render the correct content.

Alternatively, you could use the Route 53 API to dynamically create the domain names in near real time, but using the `*` wildcard appoach will likely give a better user experience, because there will be no delay in propagating the DNS change.

Comment: using *.example.com will work for anything irrespective of the user existence for that domain. How do we ensure that it loads only when there is a registered user with that subdomain

Comment: @systemdebt This would be a constraint handled by your application server, which returns an adequate response.