# How to redirect to route53 CNAME record after creation?

Tags: node.js, aws-sdk, amazon-route53

I am using AWS route53 protocol nodeJs library. I want to redirect to created CNAME record after creation. But it is taking too long time.

Can any one help?

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking.  What, specifically, is taking too long, and how long does it take?

Comment: Hi Michael, Thank you for the response. What I am doing is, In a NodeJs request, I am creating CNAME record. After that, i am trying to redirect to the same CNAME record in the same service. In this case it is not redirecting to that subdomain.

Comment: DNS record creation and availability are not immediate.     Maybe [a wildcard entry](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41675336/1695906) would be a better solution?